# Unittest a statemachine

Tags: .net, unit-testing, state-pattern

I'm new to `C#` und with their unittesting facilities. I wrote a state machine using the `state` pattern from `GoF`

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var c = new Context(SimpleStateMachine.StateInit);
        c.Run();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class SimpleStateMachine
{
    public static void StateInit(Context context)
    {
        // ... do some init
        context.State = StateConfigure;
    }
    public static void StateConfigure(Context context)
    {
        // do some conifigure
        context.State = StateMeasurement;
    }
    public static void StateMeasurement(Context context)
    {
        // do some measurement
        context.State = GetMeasurement()? StateConfigure : StateFinished;
    }
    public static void StateFinished(Context context)
    {
        // do some deinit
        context.State = (Action<Context>)null;
    }
}

public class Context
{
    public Action<Context> State { get; internal set; }

    public Context(Action<Context> state)
    {
        State = state;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (State != null)
        {
            State(this);
        }
    }
}
```

How to properly test such a statemachine? This concrete state machine is just a sample implementation. The right implementation has a lot more states and condition for transitions.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do this.

If you're truly using a strict "state machine" pattern, you need to handle side effects through monads.

If you're just looking to test the state after several inputs, you can feed it several inputs, then test the state you're expecting it to be in.

Comment: I edited my question with a more complex `FSM`. The FSM itself implements a measurement based on input files. In every case the last state should be the FinishState. But how to test the correct order of states? Additionally how to test the correct times each state gets called?

Comment: @Razer well, you could mock out individual states to determine that the state is correct after each input.